# No Java EE application template in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

Trying to create Java EE poject in InteliiJ, but can't find template for it:

[image]

I was expecting something like:
[image]

Where JavaEE is gone?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-ee.html?

Comment: What IDE edition do you use - Ultimate or Community?

Comment: I'm using Community edition, probably this is why I don't have Java EE

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons. You could try the following:

- Update your JavaEE-plugins. Look in [ File > Settings.. > plugins > updates].
- Invalide Caches [File > Invalidate Caches/Restart... ]
- Open your idea.log with [Help > Show Log in Explorer] and look for errors and post it here.
- Have you changed your Java version? Installed it in a different directory?
- Look if your environment variables 'JAVA_HOME' is set to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise templates are only available in the paid ultimate version of intellij.
So, you can either switch to Netbeans or eclipse to use those features for free.